# How to issue an update in Sqlalchemy in a single query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to use Sqlalchemy ORM to issue an update statement, but from everywhere I've looked  ([official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#updating-orm-objects), [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_orm_updating_objects.htm), other stackoverflow answers) this requires:

- execute a query to retrieve the object
- do the changes on retrieved object
- issue a commit/flush

Provided we already have a session object and a Dummy model, this results in something like:

```
dummy = session.query(Dummy).filter(Dummy.id == 1).first()
dummy.name = "dumb-dumb"
session.commit()
```

Wouldn't that make for two calls to the db? If so can I do the following to reduce it to a single call:

```
session.query(Dummy).filter(Dummy.id == 1).update({"name": "dumb-dumb"})
session.commit()
```

Would the second code block be more efficient, or it won't make any difference?

I thought of using Sqlalchmey core for that, as I know how to structure the statement, but I also need to create some listeners after insertion or an update, which require the use of ORM.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs you can use [ORM-enabled UPDATE statements](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#orm-enabled-update-statements):

```py
session.execute(update(Dummy).where(Dummy.id == 1).values(name="dumb-dumb"))
```

This won't emit an `after_update` event, but you can add an event listener for `do_orm_execute` to monitor the changes.

Comment: The problem is that this won't emit the after_insert / after_update listeners. I could use other listeners from Core, but for my use case after_insert / after_update makes the most sense.

Comment: You can use the `do_orm_execute` event to monitor this ORM-enabled update statement.